# Can't find the service

Tags: go, rpc, json-rpc, gorilla

I am trying to make `json-rpc` server in my application using `gorilla/rpc` package.

Here is my code

```
func (server *Server) ListenRPC(port string) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf(MessageListeningRPCServer, port))
    s := rpc.NewServer()
    s.RegisterCodec(json.NewCodec(), "application/json")
    s.RegisterCodec(json.NewCodec(), "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    s.RegisterService(new(RPCServer), "")
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Handle("/", s)
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(portFormatter, port), r)
}

type RPCServer struct {
}

type Response string

type Args struct {
    A, B int
}

func (server *RPCServer) Abc(r *http.Request, args *Args, response *Response) error {
    *response = "asdasdasd"
    return nil
}
```

So in cmd I run `curl` command look like this

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"method":"RPCServer.Abc","params":[{"a":3}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8090
```

and get error look like this

```
rpc: can't find service "RPCServer.Abc"
```

Comment: If you had a runnable piece of code, that would be really helpful to debug this.